# Install Windows 8 (clean) on Hybrid Drive

Tags: windows-8, uefi, hybrid-storage

I have a Sony Vaio T series (UEFI) that consists of a Hybrid Drive (SSD + HDD). I would like to install Windows 8 on the SSD and keep the Program files and other applications on the hard disk. What I could perceive was to keep the SSD as the System Drive. I'm able to install the OS on the SSD, but I run into some issues where I don't see the Microsoft Store App on my system and there are no apps on Windows 8. I tried using [this blog post](http://techtalkin.com/Thread-Build-A-Fast-Reliable-Windows-7-System-Using-A-SSD-HDD-Hybrid-Setup) but doesn't seem to fit for Windows 8.

Any help in this regard would be great. I would like the Windows 8 alone on the SSD, I don't care about the space wasted on the SSD and install other programs on my HDD.
Thanks

Comment: Wait... a [Hybrid Drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_State_Hybrid_Drive), and SSD + HDD is 2 completely different thing. SSHD (Solid State Hybrid Drive) is a normal HDD with a tiny SSD used by the HDD as cache. That article seems to refer to the fact that you need to have SSD and HDD and do a custom installation with pieces of the OS on the SSD, and some on the HDD.

Comment: It should be as simple as installing it to the drive if it doesn't work there is something else going on.